# On Android, how to read screen brightness or auto adjustment factor when system auto adjust brightness is on?

Tags: android, brightness

I tried to read screen brightness on an Android phone, on that phone the auto brightness was on, and I got a value just equals the brightness number before the auto brightness was on, I need to read the real brightness even the brightness is changing with the light sensor, or if the auto brightness factor can be read?

Answer (score 1):

I did some research and it seems that is not possible. See this answer from [Get preferred screen brightness in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4544967/get-preferred-screen-brightness-in-android/8114307#8114307).

I also tried this code:

```
int brightnessValue = Settings.System.getInt(
            getContentResolver(),
            Settings.System.SCREEN_BRIGHTNESS,
            0
);
```

But it always returns the non-automatic brightness.

Comment: Yes, I find out that it is unable to get screen brightness on auto mode, but there is a hidden API could get "screen_auto_brightness_adj",  a [-1,1] float number, this API may be closed in the future,   I am wondering why android framework was designed to disable developer to get the real screen brightness on auto mode.